# Combine three query results

Tags: sql

How to combine result of below three queries?

```
IF (select count(TTMPRCNO) from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)>0 
  (select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT',(cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'API_MIN',(cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) 
  as 'PRI_MIN'  from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)
ELSE 
  (select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN')  

IF(select count(TTMPRCNO) from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='Non ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)>0 
    select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'NON_ICICI_OFF_CNT',(cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'NON_API_MIN',(cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) 
    as 'NON_PRI_MIN' from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='Non ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518
ELSE 
    select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN'

IF(select count(TTMPRCNO) from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='SCBK' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)>0 
    select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'SCBK_OFF_CNT',(cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'SCBK_API_MIN',(cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) 
    as 'SCBK_PRI_MIN'   from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='SCBK' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518
ELSE 
    select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN'
```

Comment: maybe with a `UNION` ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQL Server and if this is the case, this should do it:

```
Select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT'
    , (cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'API_MIN'
    , (cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) as 'PRI_MIN'  
From Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark 
where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)
UNION ALL
select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN'
where not exists (select 1 from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)
UNION ALL
select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'NON_ICICI_OFF_CNT'
    ,(cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'NON_API_MIN'
    ,(cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) as 'NON_PRI_MIN' 
from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark 
where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='Non ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518
UNION ALL
select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN'
where not exists (select 1 from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)
UNION ALL
select count(TTMPRCNO) as 'NON_ICICI_OFF_CNT'
    ,(cast(SUM(cast(APE_Mn as float)) as decimal(15,2))) AS 'NON_API_MIN'
    ,(cast(round(SUM(cast(Premium_Mn as float)),2) as decimal(15,2))) as 'NON_PRI_MIN' 
from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark 
where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='Non ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518
UNION ALL 
select '0' as 'ICICI_OFF_CNT', '0.00' as 'API_MIN' ,'0.00' as 'PRI_MIN'
where not exists (select count(TTMPRCNO) from Real_Time_Login_Query_Remark  where Ibank_NonIbank_SCB ='Non ICICI Bank' and type='OFFLINE' and LotNo=5518)
```

First query is your normal query. Second query is your Else Select with a Not Exists on your if condition.
Same goes for Select 3 and 4 and Select 5 and 6.